# Domain Routing error Missing required parameters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdomain

I have facing problem in my project. I create domain routing in laravel. But when I enter the login page route in shows error

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.login.submit] [URI: login].
```

Here is my route

```
Route::domain(env('APP_DOMAIN_URL'))->group(function () {
    Route::any('/', function() {
        return 'Site is under development';
    });
});

Route::domain('{subdomain}.' . env('APP_DOMAIN_URL'))->group(function () {

    Route::group(['namespace' => 'backend'], function() {
        Route::get('login', 'AdminLoginController@showLogin')->name('admin.login');
        Route::post('login', 'AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
        Route::get('/', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
        Route::get('logout', 'AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');

    });
});
```

My login method code in Controller is

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\backend;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => ['logout']]);
    }

    public function showLogin() {
        return view('backend.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request) {
        // Validate the form data
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        // Attempt to log the user in
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1], $request->remember)) {
            // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }

        // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
        $errors = ['email' => trans('auth.failed')];
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))->withErrors($errors);
    }

    public function logout() {        
        return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
    }

}
```

And my blade file is

```
<div class="login-box-body">
    <p class="login-box-msg">Sign in to start your session</p>
    @include('backend.include.login_error')
    @include('backend.include.flashMessage')
    <form action="{{ route('admin.login.submit') }}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus placeholder="Email">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required placeholder="Password">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <div class="checkbox icheck">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : ''}}> Remember Me
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Also is there is any way to redirect if the user is not login to login page for subdomain.

I am using Laravel 5.7

My Error message

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I got the answer to one of yours, but I will need your method controller for your post route as the main error you are looking to resolve is triggered by that method and not the one you added to the answer. Resuming, can you edit the answer and add the `login` method from your controller?

Comment: @DiogoSanto I am updated my question. plz take a look

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the subdomain as a parameter to the route helper method, for example:

```
<form 
    action="{{ route('admin.login.submit', ['subdomain' => 'admin']) }}" 
    method="post">
```

Comment: Do I need to add subdomain in all the route. It is very time consuming. Is there is not any other way

Comment: Instead of {subdomain} as a parameter you could set it elsewhere, with a session or config variable for example or by some other logic and insert it in your routes file.

Comment: How could I do this? Also my subdomain are different.

Comment: `Route::domain($subdomain. ' . env('APP_DOMAIN_URL'))->group` where `$subdomain` can be set based on a session variable, or another value, depending on when you need which subdomain. If it's too complex to set the variable, I would use the paramater and set it manually on every route.

Answer (score 0):

For the last question you have, `to redirect users when logged or not, you can make use of the`Auth middleware`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    //Only Auth routes that you wish to allow, if user is authenticated
});
```

If you wish to be forceful, you can also implement a check at the top of your routes:

```
if (Auth::guest()) {
   return redirect('login');
}
```

As for your **login route**, this is what I would do to help reduce the code and separate the logic in your `method`:

At the root folder of your laravel project, run the below command in your CMD:

```
php artisan make:request LoginRequest
```

This will create a new `Class` at `app/Http/Requests`

Within this class add your validation, so when the route and POST hists your method, the validation was already triggered:

**LoginRequest class**

```
public function autorize()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return false; //User already logged in, no point in going through this again
    }
    return true; //It is a guest so lets approve it
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email'    => 'required|email|users:unique',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'email.required' => 'You need to add an email to login.',
        'email.email'    => 'The information provided does not seem to be an email.',
        ...
    ];
}
```

**Your login method at your Controller**

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{
    // You can remove the first lines that do the validation as this is triggered before arriving to the method now!
    ....
}
```

**If working with more than one domain**

Head to your `config/app.php` and add the other domains you need below the `base_domain` key:

```
return [

   'base_domain' => env('APP_BASE_DOMAIN'),
    ...
];
```

From this you will have to let Laravel know about your intentions. There are a few steps to follow and a few ways to better organize the code. I recommend [this tutorial](https://blog.pusher.com/laravel-subdomain-routing/) to help you setup subdomains in your laravel app!

Comment: Aready using the code. This code works If I am not using domain routing. But when I use domain routing thsi code not works

Comment: Having a look now! :)

Comment: @HabibHassan try my solution and check if it still triggers a problem to you